# Why does returning false?

Tags: prolog

Im working on prolog program for my homework.I have to find grandmother,aunt,uncle and grandfather , so I did something and its find the person what I looking for, after that returning false.

```
female(ayla).
female(pinar).
female(cansu).
female(dilek).
female(yaprak).
female(fatma).
female(muge).
female(nermin).
female(ezgi).
```

male(osman).
male(ulus).
male(cagri).
male(arif).
male(burak).
male(serkan).
male(talat).
male(cafer).
male(selim).
male(tolga).

parents(ayla,ulas).
parents(pinar,ayla).
parents(cansu,dilek).
parents(cagri,yaprak).
parents(arif,dilek).
parents(pinar,arif).
parents(pinar,fatma).
parents(fatma,burak).
parents(serkan,cansu).
parents(serkan,muge).
parents(talat,cagri).
parents(talat,osman).
parents(nermin,cagri).
parents(nermin,osman).
parents(osman,cafer).
parents(talat,ezgi).
parents(ezgi,selim).
parents(nermin,ezgi).
parents(cagri,tolga).

brother(ezgi,osman).
brother(ezgi,cagri).
brother(osman,ezgi).
brother(osman,cagri).
brother(cagri,osman).
brother(cagri,ezgi).

brother(ayla,fatma).
brother(ayla,arif).
brother(fatma,ayla).
brother(fatma,arif).
brother(arif,fatma).
brother(arif,ayla).

brother(cansu,muge).
brother(muge,cansu).

`grandmother(X,Z):-
    female(X),
        parents(X, Y), parents(Y, Z).


grandfather(X,Z):-
    male(X),
        parents(X,Y), parents(Y,Z).


uncle(X,Z):-
    male(X),    
        parents(Y,Z),
        male(Y),
        brother(X,Y).

aunt(X,Z):-
    female(X),
        parents(Y,Z),
        female(Y),
        brother(X,Y).`

[my data(as a screenshoot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWDEh.png)

[functions as a screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKXzR.png)

[and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLUGM.png)

Comment: Please don't just link screen shots, but put the program code and output in your question. That would improve the readability a lot.

Comment: I think that more readability now